# Static files (.js, .css) triggering ASP.NET pipeline

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

In my ASP.NET MVC application the ASP.NET pipeline is being invoked for static files (such as css and javascript files).  This shouldn't be happening, right?  (I mean, what's the point in processing them?).

Maybe I'm completely wrong here, and ASP.NET *should* be processing these files - If so please let me know!

Otherwise, What's the best practice for setting up IIS or ASP.NET MVC so that these files are just spat out rather than processed by ASP.NET? (Only problem I can think of it possibly route handling)

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Currently I'm serving from the ASP.NET development server, so would like to know options regarding this, but also for IIS6 and 7 if possible.

Comment: Which version of IIS are you using?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC shouldn't really be doing anything with requests to the content folder if you have the ignore route for it... `routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*pathInfo}");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Visual Studio development server uses the ASP.NET pipeline to handle **all** requests including javascript and css. This is not the case for IIS unless explicitly configured.

Comment: To add clarification: The VS Dev Server uses the ASP.NET Hosting API's to create the Web Server; so naturally all requests are handled by ASP.NET. IIS on the other hand doesn't require ASP.NET to function, and knows how to serve up files without using the ASP.NET Hosting API's.